# I'm having trouble with my nav bar animations

Tags: jquery

I have a horizontal nav bar I'm using for a site for a school project. My JS animates my nav list items but not the way I would like it to. It's adding the height to the bottom and I would like to add it to the top. I've tried position:absolute but it completely messes up my nav when I do that. I only have the nav bar on this fiddle, but if you need more I can provide it. Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ajcherup/sE7Ez/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '+=20px'
        });
    });
    $('li').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '-=20px'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid. You cannot wrap other tags around a LI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the animation, when you add the height, also add a corresponding amount of negative top margin as well. In this way, the 'height' *will* be added to the bottom but the whole thing will shift up making it look like the height is being added to the top...

Updated fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/sE7Ez/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '+=20px',
        marginTop: '-20px'
    });


});
$('li').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '-=20px',
        marginTop: '+20px'
    });

});

});
```

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to stackoverflow.